# Can't convert 'data annotations' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

From the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k(v=vs.100).aspx

i've created a customeValidators.cs page, which checks if data entered exists in Db.
This works. However when i try to call this from the necessary pagewith

```
protected void runUniqueReference(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = (CustomValidators.UniqueReference(BOQRefTextBox.Text));
}
```

i get the error with `CustomValidators.UniqueReference`, can't convert 'data annotations' to 'bool'
any idea?
EDIT;

```
 public static ValidationResult UniqueReference(string Reference)
    {
        ContextDB db = new  ContextDB();

        var lisStoredInDB =
            (from Bill in db.Bill_Of_Quantities
             where Bill.Reference == Reference
             select Bill.Reference).ToList();

        if (lisStoredInDB.Count != 0)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("This reference is already stored in the database, Please enter another"));
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

Comment: what's the return type of CustomValidators.UniqueReference(string...) ?

Comment: What is `UniqueReference` and its return type? There is no method called UniqueReference in CustomValidators class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args.IsValid` is of type `bool`, and `CustomValidators.UniqueReference` mustn't return a value of that type. Therefore,

```
args.IsValid = (CustomValidators.UniqueReference(BOQRefTextBox.Text));
```

won't work since you can't assign whatever the return value of `UniqueReference` is to `IsValid`.

Since `UniqueReference` returns an [`ValidationResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationresult.aspx), it should probably look like this:

```
args.IsValid = (CustomValidators.UniqueReference(BOQRefTextBox.Text)).IsValid;
```